# Why does [cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; not work?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, detailtextlabel

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

doesn't work. Any way to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITableViewCell` `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` both don't behave like normal `UILabel`'s. This probably is because a UITableViewCell draws it's text instead of using a `UILabel` for performance reasons. This results in inconsistent behaviour because the backgroundColor property is ignored by the cell's drawing.

Stick with the default `UITableViewCell` if your desired functionality fits within what the Apple engineers have designed to be handled by a default cell. For all other functionality create your own subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: hmm, fair enough. :) it was an attempt to solve another problem, and not a necessity. :)

Answer (score 0):

set this in table view delegate method

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView   willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
[cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}
```

Answer (score -3):

cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];